# running/serving an angular app in test environment with test flag

Tags: angular, package.json, test-environments

i am able to use ng serve -c test on local.
how do i serve the app in test and production machines specifying test configuration?

i have changed pipeline yml to 'npm run build' n changed

```
'scripts':
build: 'ng build --configuration=test'
```

in package.json.
This will take care of the build.

In angular.json,i have set both 'build' and 'serve' as recommended in samples.

```
'serve':
 test':'browsertarget:build:test'
```

but it looks like we have to build and serve.
i can build for a specific environment on pipeline...but what's the equivalent for ng serve- c test outside local conditions?